# pyinstaller Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have been searching since a couple of days for a solution without success.
We have a windows service build to copy some files from one location to another one.

So I build the code shown below with Python 3.7.
The full coding can be found on [Github](https://github.com/petepall/FileCopy_Service).

When I run the service using python all is working fine, I can install the service and also start the service.

This using commands:

**Install the service:**

- python jis53_backup.py install

**Run the service:**

- python jis53_backup.py start

When I now compile this code using pyinstaller with command:

- pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=win32timezone jis53_backup.py

After the exe is created, I can install the service but when trying to start the service I get the error:

> Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or
>   control request in a timely fashion

I have gone through multiple posts on Stackoverflow and on Google related to this error however, without success. I don't have the option to install the python 3.7 programs on the PC's that would need to run this service. That's why we are trying to get a .exe build.

I have made sure to have the path updated according to the information that I found in the different questions.

Image of path definitions:

[image]

I also copied the pywintypes37.dll file.

*From -> Python37\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32*

*To -> Python37\Lib\site-packages\win32*

Does anyone have any other suggestions on how to get this working?

```
'''
    Windows service to copy a file from one location to another
    at a certain interval.
'''
import sys
import time
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

import servicemanager
import win32serviceutil

import win32service
from HelperModules.CheckFileExistance import check_folder_exists, create_folder
from HelperModules.ReadConfig import (check_config_file_exists,
                                      create_config_file, read_config_file)
from ServiceBaseClass.SMWinService import SMWinservice

sys.path += ['filecopy_service/ServiceBaseClass',
             'filecopy_service/HelperModules']


class Jis53Backup(SMWinservice):
    _svc_name_ = "Jis53Backup"
    _svc_display_name_ = "JIS53 backup copy"
    _svc_description_ = "Service to copy files from server to local drive"

    def start(self):
        self.conf = read_config_file()
        if not check_folder_exists(self.conf['dest']):
            create_folder(self.conf['dest'])

        self.isrunning = True

    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    def main(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        while self.isrunning:
            # Copy the files from the server to a local folder
            # TODO: build function to trigger only when a file is changed.
            copy_tree(self.conf['origin'], self.conf['dest'], update=1)
            time.sleep(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'install':
        if not check_config_file_exists():
            create_config_file()

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(Jis53Backup)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(Jis53Backup)
```

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: @njho, no luck thus far. I can run the service via python, but can't get it working via the exe.

Comment: Hey @peter thanks for the response. I'm still playing with mine, but I've gotten it halfway working. Check that the Python environment variables are in your SYSTEM path as well. That was what fixed it for me. Let me know if it works

Comment: @njho, I have python in my SYSTEM path but still it's not working for me.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem. Wondering if it's a python3.7 thing... since there are some many examples using 3.6

Comment: @Peter I too have the same issue, Did you solved it?

Comment: @Jisson, @M Leonard, I was not able to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing this issue after compiling using `pyinstaller`. For me, the issue was that I was using the paths to configs and logs file in dynamic way, for ex:

```
curr_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
configs_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'configs', 'app_config.json')
opc_configs_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'configs', 'opc.json')
log_file_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'logs', 'application.log')
```

This was working fine when I was starting the service using `python service.py install/start`. But after compiling it using `pyinstaller`, it always gave me error of not starting in timely fashion.

To resolve this, I made all the dynamic paths to static, for ex:

```
configs_path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ScantechOPC\\configs\\app_config.json'
opc_configs_path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ScantechOPC\\configs\\opc.json'
debug_file = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ScantechOPC\\logs\\application.log'
```

After compiling via `pyinstaller`, it is now working fine without any error. Looks like when we do dynamic path, it doesn't get the actual path to files and thus it gives error.

Hope this solves your problem too. Thanks

Comment: You are my hero. 
How did you figure it out .. I haven't found any details about the failure ?
Thanks this stuff was getting me mad. :)

Comment: `How did you figure it out` I broke my code in small portions and then use pyinstaller and realized that the dynamic path was the only point which was creating issue.